# Magento1 - Missing core/session at event sales_order_save_before

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

I need to pass 2 Vars from a controller to the order.
So I create a controller where i persist values at the `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')`.

I also create an event and its observer method:

```
<events>
            <sales_order_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <xyz_facebook_add_userdata_to_order>
                        <class>Xyz_Facebook_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>addFacebookMessengerUserDataToOrder</method>
                    </xyz_facebook_add_userdata_to_order>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_before>
        </events>
```

The Controller with an event Action method:

```
public function eventAction()
    {
        $aFBInput = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        $sUserRef = $aFBInput['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['optin']['user_ref'];
        $sSubscriptionTimestamp = $aFBInput['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['timestamp'];

        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setXyzFacebookSubDateTime($sSubscriptionTimestamp);
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setXyzFacebookUserRef($sUserRef);
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.0','200', true);
    }
```

As you see i set the custom var `setXyzFacebookSubDateTime` and `setXyzFacebookUserRef`.

If I Log this values out, I can see the values in my logfile!
But if I save the order in the checkout, the values in the observer method are empty.

```
public function addFacebookMessengerUserDataToOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {

        /**
         * @var $order Mage_Sales_Model_Order
         */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $coreSession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');

        $sSubscriptionTimestamp = $coreSession->getXyzFacebookSubDateTime();
        $sUserRef = $coreSession->getXyzFacebookUserRef();

        $order->setData('xyz_facebook_user_ref', $sUserRef);
        $order->setData('xyz_facebook_subscription_dateime', $sSubscriptionTimestamp);

    }
```

the vars `$sSubscriptionTimestamp`, `$sUserRef` are empty!

Whats wrong??

Comment: My guess is that you didn't pass a name to the `core/session` constructor so when you call the session in your observer, it `init` a new instance. Try storing it in customer session `Mage::getSingleton(customer/session')` instead, which should persist for the entire customer session.

Comment: It do not work!

Comment: I tested in my server for both `core/session` and `customer/session`, both work. I managed to retrieve the var I set with `getter` consistently.

Comment: What you mean with getter. I use f.e. $coreSession->getXyzFacebookUserRef();.
Please post your example. and you use the event sales_order_save_before ?

Comment: Sorry, I was really tied up in the past days, but I am glad you sorted this out!

Answer (score 1):

Good to know that you have already figured out the issue and fixed it. I got another solution after testing the code on my local. In this case, the session works fine.

**Answer**

You're having an issue picking up the correct session because Magento stores its session ID in a different cookie than typical PHP apps. You need to first initialize a core session, and tell it to look at a cookie named frontend instead of whatever PHP defaults to, so instead of starting a new session it will use the existing one. Your code should look like the following:

```
public function eventAction()
{
    $aFBInput = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $sUserRef = $aFBInput['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['optin']['user_ref'];
    $sSubscriptionTimestamp = $aFBInput['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['timestamp'];

    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setXyzFacebookSubDateTime($sSubscriptionTimestamp);
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setXyzFacebookUserRef($sUserRef);
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.0', '200', true);
}
```

Thumbs Up for you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much it will help, but a situation like this I'd usually try make sure I'm using the correct event for the job.

To start, I'd recommend switching the event you're observing in your `config.xml` file to `sales_order_place_before` rather than `sales_order_save_before`. I've personally noticed issues with observing `sales_order_save_before` as it might be fired just a little too late for what you need.

See here for a list of most (all?) the events fired in Magento 1.9.x. It's helped me in the past, hope it helps you. https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/

Comment: Hi, i test the event "sales_order_place_after" but at this point there is no session available. It make no sense to observe the controller dispatch event, because i want  only fire this observer event if a order is set ( before or after ). And this order events has no session available :(  -- Any idea, how i can use another event where the session is avaiable and the new order is passes into this event?

Comment: Hi @AndreBubner, I assume you're experiencing a different issue here then. Maybe  it's based on your environment, browser, cookie config in Magento, I can't really tell from the info we have. 
I've just tried calling `Mage::getSingleton('core/session');` on the `sales_order_place_before` *and* `sales_order_save_before` events myself to test this out and managed to get a positive return without issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is issue is solved.
Problem was, the external Hook which calls my controller create a new Session.

So i use the quote->getId() to add a namespace in the session, to open the current one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My test code using @PROGOSTECH method, although using `customer/session` works as well

Controller:

```
public function setVarAction()
{
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', ['name'=>'var_ab'])->setVarA('This is Var A');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('test_set_var');
    Zend_Debug::dump(Mage::getSingleton('core/session', ['name'=>'var_ab'])->getVarA()); 
}

public function getVarAction()
{
    $var = [
        'varA' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session', ['name'=>'var_ab'])->getVarA(),
        'VarB' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session', ['name'=>'var_ab'])->getVarB()
    ];
    Zend_Debug::dump($var); 
}
```

Observer

```
public function getVar($observer)
{
    $var = 'Get: '.Mage::getSingleton('core/session', ['name'=>'var_ab'])->getVarA();
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', ['name'=>'var_ab'])->setVarB($var);
}
```

Output of setVar

```
string(13) "This is Var A"
```

Output of getVar

```
array(2) {
  ["varA"] => string(13) "This is Var A"
  ["VarB"] => string(18) "Get: This is Var A"
}
```